# Recovering Blockchaininfo wallet in Electrum wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, blockchain.info, electrum, seed

I have my wallet in blockchaininfo and I did the backup of my 12 words (SEED).

I would like to open this wallet in Electrum, I notice that Electrum allow to recover a wallet using a SEED from another wallet (BIP39 seed).

When I type my seed and I choose the BIP39 option, I can click on next step where I have to choose the type of the addresses on my wallet: legacy (p2pkh); p2psh-segwit (p2wpkh-p2sh); native segwit (p2wpkh). I am not sure what those options mean, so I just choose the default option (native segwit). After this step, I just need to set up a password.

But when I do all these steps, I cannot see any Bitcoins in my Electrum wallet, Am I doing something wrong in the steps or is not possible recovering blockchaininfo wallet on Electrum wallet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Begin anew via file > new/restore, enter a unique filename and click ok, Follow on-screen instructions for the rest. This time choose p2sh-segwit if the addresses in your blockchain.info wallet begin with 3 or p2pkh if they begin with 1.

Native segwit generates addresses beginning with bc1. I don't think blockchain.info generates native segwit addresses at this point in time.

Comment: I did as you said and I could see some transaction in Electrum when I choose p2pkh, but my balance is still 0, I think it is because on blockchain you can create a lot of wallets, and these wallets generate a lot of addresses. I received BTC in addresses that start with all of those paths (3, 1 and bc), but in Electrum I have already tried all those paths and I cannot see my balance there, not sure about that, maybe I have to customize this path, as it is said in one option: "You can override the suggested derivation path".

Comment: it would be easier to simply make a new wallet in electrum and simply send all your coins to it via blockchain.info. however if you insist on restoring from bc.i seed proceed as previously with one difference. increment the last number in the path. so for example you make a p2pkh wallet with the path m/44'/0'/1'/ instead of m/44'/0'/0'/. this last number is for your hd account which blockchain.info calls wallets. do this for all script types (p2pkh, p2wpkh etc.). you can keep incrementing that last number until you arrive at a wallet with your whole balance.

Comment: Thank you, the only reason I want to restore my blockchain wallet in Electrum is if I lost access in my blockchain, I could recover it in Electrum. This is just for educational propose for myself, not exactly a need. Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 1):

A mnemonic seed phrase can be used to derive an unbounded number of addresses, so you need to supply some additional information, so that the wallet software will know which addresses to derive.

This additional information includes the [derivation pathway](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/67849/how-to-traverse-bitcoin-addresses-in-hd-wallet/67881#67881), and the [address type](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/76965/how-is-it-possible-that-the-same-wif-private-key-generates-two-different-address).

There are some standards developed to specify these variables, see for example BIP 32, 39, 44, 84.

So to recover your wallet, you'll want to figure out first which derivation path the original wallet used (you should hopefully be able to find this in the software docs / help), as well as the address type used (should be self-evident, based on the address prefix).